# How to retrieve radiogroup data from database in JAVA? M Using Java Swing & SQLite

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, user-interface, jdbc

Can anyone tell me how to retrieve radiogroup data from database? Values are inserting through radiobutton but isn't retrieving from database.
coding is as follows:

```
while(rs.next())
{
    String db_name = rs.getString("name");
    String db_add = rs.getString("address");
    String db_gender = rs.getString("gender");

    Text_name.setText(db_name);
    Text_address.setText(db_add);
    if(db_gender=="Male")
    {
        RadioMale.isSelected();
    }
    else if(db_gender=="Female")
    {
        RadioFemale.isSelected();
        // GenderGroup.equals(RadioFemale);
    }
}
```

NOTE: RadioMale & RadioFemale are Variable names of RadioButton..
db_name & db_add are working perfectly just getting issue on gender.. Help me out please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a string compare, should you be using the following;

```
db_gender.equals("Male")
```

-Kaz

Comment: Yeah I am comparing string & also tried your idea but didn't work out :(

Comment: Are you sure you are getting 'Male' with a capital and not 'male', you could try the 'equalsIgnoreCase' method.

Comment: Yeah I stored "Male" & "Female" values in Database

Comment: Additionally you should also be using 'setSelected(true)' instead of 'isSelected()'. The 'isSelected()' method will return a boolean if the radio box is selected or not.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected%28boolean%29

Comment: Basically I need to search database via name. When user Enters his/her name then values associated with it would be revealed in respective textfields. All of the textfields are working just getting issue in Selecting Radio Button.. Is there any way to select value of Radiobutton?

Comment: Yeah did it.. Thanks Kazagha :) setSelected() is the thing...

Answer (score 0):

setSelected() is the required answer
RadioMale.setSelected(); RadioFemale.setSelected();
Thanks to Kazagha for correcting me :) Thanks for your time :)